# Third-party library jars analysis required

Tags: maven, repository

Is there any way to do analysis of 3rd party java library jars.

There huge set of jars being used by application of obsolete version but stable.
Is there any way to find out report which shows what are my repository version is and what is market latest jars...

I just don't want to keep version as latest and product stability is a very important factor.
Going through each and every jar and do research is really cumbersome.

Is there any better method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [versions plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/).

```
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```

This will scan a project's dependencies and produces a report of those dependencies which have newer versions available.